# Form Font Embedding

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

It's a while that I'm trying to figure out what's happening in this piece of code.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr AddFontMemResourceEx(IntPtr pbFont, 
    uint cbFont, IntPtr pdv, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] ref uint pcFonts);

public static PrivateFontCollection myFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
public static FontFamily RobotoBold = null;
public static FontFamily RobotoThin = null;

public enum Fonts
{
    Roboto_Bold = 0,
    Roboto_Thin = 1
}

public static void loadFonts()
{
   Array fonts = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fonts));

   foreach (Fonts font in fonts)
   {
       byte[] fontData = (byte[])Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(font.ToString());
       IntPtr fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
       uint dummy = 0;
       myFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, fontData.Length);
       AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)fontData.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
   }

   RobotoBold = Program.myFontCollection.Families[(int)Program.Fonts.Roboto_Bold];
   RobotoThin = Program.myFontCollection.Families[(int)Program.Fonts.Roboto_Thin];
}
```

Actually it reads the .ttf I've embedded as resources, but if I debug, inside the FontFamilys I read this message:

```
{Name = The name 'name' does not exist in the current context}
```

I've already tried to figure out what's happening, but can't find my error.
The resource is being read correctly using the ResourceManager, but I think something's wrong while adding the font.

Comment: The code is borken, you must not call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() until *after* the font can no longer be used.  Usually after your form is closed.  Everything *seems* to work just fine, but the font can randomly get corrupted and your program may crash with an AVE.

Comment: I cannot get the point. so when i call FreeCoTaskMem I basically release the resource?